# Is Julia not evaluating the Function?

Tags: julia

I'm playing around with the Collatz conjecture (see below), and I have this function:

```
function txpo(max_n)
    for n ∈ 1:max_n
        x = n
        while x ≥ n  &&  x != 1
            x = iseven(x) ? x÷2 : 3x+1
        end
    end
end
```

On purpose I don't return anything or check anything, to make it as fast as possible. And boy, is it fast... - actually too fast, I think.

```
using BenchmarkTools
@btime txpo(100_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000)

2.337 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```

Running through 10^38 `while` loops takes only 2ns? Julia is fast, but I would be surprised if it was that fast. It seems like the code is not evaluated. Or what am I missing here?

---

*Collatz Conjecture*
Take a whole number and build a series by using the following rule: if the number is even divide by 2; if the number is odd multiply by 3 and add 1. Conjecture: every series will end up in the loop `4-2-1-4`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, the whole function body is optimized out:

```
julia> function txpo(max_n)
           for n ∈ 1:max_n
               x = n
               while x ≥ n  &&  x != 1
                   x = iseven(x) ? x÷2 : 3x+1
               end
           end
       end
txpo (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @code_llvm txpo(100000000000)
;  @ REPL[1]:1 within `txpo`
define void @julia_txpo_179(i64 signext %0) #0 {
top:
;  @ REPL[1]:5 within `txpo`
  ret void
}
```

If you use `10^38`, this only changes the function signature to accept 128-bit integers.

The LLVM IR code is basically the same as this Julia code:

```
julia_txpo_179(_0::Int64) = nothing
```

This makes perfect sense because why execute a function that doesn't return anything that depends on its computations and has no side-effects?

Finally, the native code that your CPU executes is literally `retq`, a.k.a. "return to caller":

```
julia> @code_native txpo(100000000000)
    .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
; ┌ @ REPL[1]:5 within `txpo`
    retq
    nopw    %cs:(%rax,%rax)
; └

julia>
```

Comment: Does it make perfect sense? I mean the idea is that the calculations are done. Is there a way to force julia to do it? Of course I can add side effects, but that makes the calculations slower than I want to.

Comment: "Is there a way to force julia to do it?" - why do this, though? The function will always return `nothing` anyway and produce no side-effects. Essentially, it doesn't do anything. What are its results? There are no results, just `nothing`, always. On the other hand, it will _never_ return if the Collatz conjecture is false, so that's a kind of result. However, deciding whether a function will terminate is hard (see "halting problem"), so LLVM apparently decides that it _will_ terminate (yay, LLVM proved Collatz!). You could return the number of times the `while` loop terminated, for example.

Comment: Related, I think: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/40009